# Passing Functions via navigate hook in React web

Tags: reactjs, navigation

I have a very complex in one of my functional components (componentA) that I need to call from another component (componentB). This isn't your usual child component so I can't pass the function as a prop. It would also be massively complex to make this function global because the function is in charge of handling a lot of state manipulation in its functional component.
The reason this is tricky is because we navigate from componentA to componentB using the navigate hook like so : `navigate('posts/${datePath}', {state:{date: date, location: selectedLocation}});`

The way I pass data to the second component is the way I'd also like to pass a function. But if there's a better approach, I'd love to hear it and I'll change the question title to reflect the better approach.